# BIRT SQL Null Case Scenario

Tags: sql, birt

I'm using the following SQL statement to retrieve various information on a work order. However, some of them don't have an asset listed (NULL) and in that case I'm getting 0 rows:

```
select PM17, WORKORDER.PMNUM, WORKORDER.ASSETNUM, ASSET.DESCRIPTION, ASSET.MANUFACTURER, EQASSETNUM, WORKORDER.LOCATION, LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION, PM.ROUTE, TARGSTARTDATE, TARGCOMPDATE, PM.NEXTDATE
from WORKORDER 
JOIN ASSET ON WORKORDER.ASSETNUM = ASSET.ASSETNUM
JOIN PM ON WORKORDER.PMNUM = PM.PMNUM
JOIN LOCATIONS ON WORKORDER.LOCATION = LOCATIONS.LOCATION
WHERE WORKORDER.WONUM='1011';
```

How can I modify my statement to work on both cases (with or without ASSETNUM)?

Case 1 (ASSETNUM != NULL)--> Shows all fields selected

Case 2 (ASSETNUM = NULL) --> Shows fields that are not dependant on the ASSETNUM and returns null for the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select PM17, WORKORDER.PMNUM, WORKORDER.ASSETNUM, ASSET.DESCRIPTION, ASSET.MANUFACTURER, EQASSETNUM, WORKORDER.LOCATION, LOCATIONS.DESCRIPTION, PM.ROUTE, TARGSTARTDATE, TARGCOMPDATE, PM.NEXTDATE
from WORKORDER 
LEFT JOIN ASSET ON WORKORDER.ASSETNUM = ASSET.ASSETNUM
JOIN PM ON WORKORDER.PMNUM = PM.PMNUM
JOIN LOCATIONS ON WORKORDER.LOCATION = LOCATIONS.LOCATION
WHERE WORKORDER.WONUM='1011';
```